# window.location disconnecting websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, window.location

I want to open a download link without opening a blank page (then, I won't be using `window.open`). Then I'm using `window.location.href` or `window.location.assign`. But the problem is that both methods disconnects my websockets connection. How can I workaround this?

Just to be clearer, no error messages are thrown and I tested it on chrome. Websockets just stops working.